# Swift how to jump to next uitextfield

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextview

I have a form with many UITextFields and I'd like the user to have the ability to jump to the next after typing.

Nor "Next" neither "Continue" does anything when I set if I set it in the "Return Key" section on my storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
self.fnTexf.returnKeyType = .next
```

//

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method


    if  let next = self.view.viewWithTag(textfield.tag + 1) as? UITextfeild
    {
        next.becomeFirstResponder()
    } 
     else
       {
           textField.resignFirstResponder()

        }


    return true
 }
```

Comment: So what if I have 50 form elements? Do I really need to do all this in the 9th version of xcode? Android has "nextfocus", is there anything similar in Xcode?

Comment: you can access the next with tag

Comment: Can you share how and where I can call this "textFieldShouldReturn"?

Comment: Actually I typed that wrong, these are UITextFields/input forms

Comment: @breakline do you have to use textView ? , what about textfield ?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: see connect all your textfeilds as outletCollection which gives you an array of them then for loop all and set incrementing tag and delegate

Comment: if you have 50 textfeilds i recommend using stackView to insert them in code

Comment: Thanks, i think I get it, well I already have the textfields so code is not an option, but they are in a stack view, I just wanted a quick way to do this like on Android

Comment: Also note instead of self.view.viewWithTag it will be indexing your array of textfeilds as the former is for textfeilds setted in IB ,  keep going